# Alignment of text not correct

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

How would I make the position of the name of my referees be alligned on the same row?

In the picture below, I would like to make the "Name of person" on the right to be aligned nicely with the "Name of person" on the left.

Note that I need to put more lines of address for one person, I cannot change the number of lines that I have.

My LaTeX code is below

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, xcolor, lipsum, bibentry}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrbase,scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings} % pagestyle with page number
\lohead{My Name}



\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}\bfseries\Huge John Doe \end{center}
\vspace{1em}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.70\textwidth}
Address Line 1\\
Address Line 2\\
Address Line 3\\
Address Line 4\\
Address Line 5
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.48\textwidth}
Mobile: 123-456789\\
Email: myemail@gmail.com\\
Date of Birth: 01/01/2012\\
Citizenship: My citizenship
\end{minipage}
\vspace{2pt}

\section*{Referees}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.70\textwidth}
\textbf{Name of person}\\
\textit{Position}\\
Address 1\\
Address 1\\
Address 1\\
Address 1\\
Contact no. :+123-1234567
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.48\textwidth}
\textbf{Name of person}\\
\textit{Position}\\
Address 1\\
Address 1\\
Address 1\\
Address 1\\
Address 1\\
Address 1\\
Contact no. :+123-1234567
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`minipage` doesn't have a `[ht]` option (You need `[t]`))